# Method undefined: manageConnectedSocket()

Tags: android, bluetooth

We want to remote a roboter via Bluetooth. Now we are using the android example. we want to connect as client. The code before this part is working. Now we get an error at:

> manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);

"The method is undefined". What can we do to solve this problem ? Thanks for answers.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html), `manageConnectedSocket` doesn't exist.

> manageConnectedSocket() is a fictional method in the application that
>   will initiate the thread for transferring data, which is discussed in
>   the section about Managing a Connection.

And you haven't defined it in your code. You need to create the method yourself, or follow the rest of the Android tutorial.

Comment: Yeah, it is unfortunate that there isn't a basic example of this method (manageConnectedSocket) included in the sample also. :(