# Receive/Send message with Bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm new to Android Bluetooth, and I'm following the [Google Developers documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/transfer-data). I don't quite understand how to send & receive message using...

```java
        public void run() {
            mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream.
                    numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                    Message readMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                            MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                            mmBuffer);
                    readMsg.sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);

                // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
                Message writtenMsg = handler.obtainMessage(
                        MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
                writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

                // Send a failure message back to the activity.
                Message writeErrorMsg =
                        handler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("toast",
                        "Couldn't send data to the other device");
                writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
                handler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);
            }
        }
```

... this part of the sample code, in `private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {...}`.

1. It says "Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity", while the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message#sendToTarget()) says "Sends this Message to the Handler specified by getTarget()". So, where is the received message sent to? How to get the received message?
2. `write(byte[] bytes)` says "// Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device". Does it mean like I can only call this thing in `MainActivity.java`? And since `ConnectedThread` is a private inner class, is it like I need to write a wrapper function in its parent class?
3. Are these related to the fictional method `manageMyConnectedSocket(socket)` in connection thread, as mentioned in [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices) of the documentation and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102533/method-undefined-manageconnectedsocket)?

```java
...
           if (socket != null) {
               // A connection was accepted. Perform work associated with
               // the connection in a separate thread.
               manageMyConnectedSocket(socket);
               mmServerSocket.close();
               break;
           }
...
```

Comment: Try looking at [How to send/receive messages via bluetooth Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45140098/how-to-send-receive-messages-via-bluetooth-android-studio).

Comment: @AliasCartellano Thank you very much for that post! It is very informative. May I ask, in that post, is it like receiving the data is done by: `final String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, mmInStream.read(mmBuffer));`? It seems like the Handler handler hasn't been used throughout the whole program.